# C++ ODBC MS SQL "Function sequence error" when trying to put jpg file into database

Tags: c++, odbc

My program saves screenshots to jpg files, then it takes those jpg files, opens it, and put into the MS SQL database (into VARBINARY[MAX] field). The problem is - these screenshots have different size depending on colors. When my program takes "dark" screenshots  - everything is ok. But when there is more "white" on screen - my function returns "Function sequence error". Can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Here is the whole function (with my comments in some 'weak' places for me):

```
int CreateDatabaseRecord(char *dateTime, char *userAccount, char* picturePath)
{

//preparing request 

    SQLLEN cbImageSize, lbytes;
    PTR pParmID;

    char SQL[1024] = "INSERT INTO screenshots (timedate, user_account, screenshot_path, pic) VALUES ('";

    strcat(SQL, dateTime);
    strcat(SQL, "', '");
    strcat(SQL, userAccount);
    strcat(SQL, "', '");
    strcat(SQL, picturePath);
    strcat(SQL, "', ?)");



    //working with jpg file
    string s = (string) picturePath;

    ifstream f;
    f.open(s.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::ate);
    size_t sz = (size_t) f.tellg();
    f.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    char *ptr = new char[sz]; 
    f.read(ptr, sz);
    f.close();

    SWORD cbBatch =  sz;
    lbytes = (SDWORD) sz;

    cbImageSize = SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC(lbytes);

    SQLSMALLINT DataType2, DecimalDigits2, Nullable2;

    SQLUINTEGER ParamSize2;


    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, &stmt);
    if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        LogSQLErrorDescription(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
        return -9;
    }


    ret = SQLPrepareA(stmt, (SQLCHAR *) SQL, SQL_NTS);
    ret = SQLDescribeParam(stmt, 1, &DataType2, &ParamSize2, &DecimalDigits2, &Nullable2);


    if ((ret != SQL_SUCCESS) && (ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) && (ret != SQL_NEED_DATA)) {

        LogSQLErrorDescription(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
        return 9;

    }


    ret = SQLBindParameter(stmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, DataType2, ParamSize2, 0, (VOID *) 1, 0,
                           &cbImageSize);



    if ((ret != SQL_SUCCESS) && (ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) && (ret != SQL_NEED_DATA)) {

        LogWrite("SQLBindParam init failed");
        return 9;

    }






    ret = SQLExecDirect(stmt, (UCHAR *) SQL, SQL_NTS);
    if ((ret != SQL_SUCCESS) && (ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) && (ret != SQL_NEED_DATA)) {

        LogSQLErrorDescription(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);

        return 9;

    }


    ret = SQLParamData(stmt, &pParmID);
    if (ret == SQL_NEED_DATA) { 
    //putting data parts into DB      
        while (lbytes > cbBatch) {

            ret = SQLPutData(stmt, (SQLCHAR *) ptr, cbBatch);

            lbytes -= cbBatch;
            ptr += cbBatch;
        }


//"Function sequence error" raises here (when putting the final block):

        ret = SQLPutData(stmt, ptr, lbytes);


        delete[] ptr; //not shure about this
        ptr = 0; //and this


        if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS) {
            LogWrite("SQLParmData failed");
            LogSQLErrorDescription(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);

            return 9;

        }

    }
    else {
        LogSQLErrorDescription(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
        return 9;
    }

    ret = SQLParamData(stmt, &pParmID); //finalizing request


    if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS) {

        LogSQLErrorDescription(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);


        return 9;

    }


    LogWrite("Database record successfully added");

    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);




return 0;
}
```

The second problem of using this function in a loop - is a memory leak. My program uses exactly the same amount of memory more as the screenshot size after each iteration of loop. Why can it happen? I `delete[] ptr`, what else should i do? Thanks for answers.

UPD. Problem solved. All i had to do is to add ONE LETTER =):

`SDWORD cbBatch`, not `SWORD cbBatch`.

Comment: Ok, i think i localized one error: `SWORD cbBatch =  sz' becomes negative when the screenshot is "white"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The second problem of using this function in a loop - is a memory leak. My program uses exactly the same amount of memory more as the screenshot size after each iteration of loop. Why can it happen? I delete[] ptr, what else should i do? Thanks for answers.

In the `while (lbytes > cbBatch) { ... }` loop, you change the ptr pointer. You need to store the original address in order to be able to delete the whole allocated buffer afterwards.

E.g. replace

```
char *ptr = new char[sz];
```

with

```
char *buf = new char[sz];
char *ptr = buf;
```

and replace

```
delete[] ptr; //not shure about this
ptr = 0;      //and this
```

with

```
delete[] buf;
```

This should clearify the memory leak problem.